# How can I make a Java subprocess communicate back and forth with parent process in a loop?

Tags: java, process

I'm currently learning about processes and I've been trying with no luck to make a process (the class that I execute directly from terminal) call a subprocess, send it a message, and then receive a message in return, and that process should repeat infinitely. This should be possible without re-creating the subprocess over and over.

I've been told that I'd need to use a loop inside the subprocess class, but doing so just makes my program hang, because it keeps waiting infinitely for the subprocess to finish. I've been searching the web for a long while but haven't found a solution yet.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;


public class MainProcess {

    static BufferedReader scanner = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "";
    Process subprocess = null;
    try { 
            subprocess = new ProcessBuilder("java", "Subprocess").start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        while (!s.equals("exit")) {
            try {
                s = scanner.readLine();            
                OutputStream os = subprocess.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
                bw.write(s+"\r");
                bw.flush();

                try{
                    subprocess.waitFor();
                }catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                InputStream inputStream = subprocess.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String linea;
                while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(linea);
        
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the child process code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Subprocess {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
             System.out.println(reader.readLine().toUpperCase());  
        } catch (IOException ex){

        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I execute it like this, the program would ask me for input. For example if I send "message", I get back "MESSAGE" in this case. It doesn't work again of course, because then the subprocess is over (I get a error message about the Stream being closed). I've used a while loop for the readLine() call in the subprocess class, but that just makes the Main program wait forever for the subprocess to finish, and that never happens. I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, so I don't wish to post a working answer. However here are some hints that may help you towards your own solution.

1. use try with resources for all streams you open, this ensures they are closed in timely manner:

   ```
    try(BufferedXXXX stream = ... ) {
        ... do something to input or output
    }
   ```
2. You do need to re-instate the `while` loop in `Subprocess`, otherwise the sub-process can never handle more than one line of input. Test your sub-process independently of `MainProcess`, it must exit when the input ends:

   ```
   // should print HELLO and exit:
   echo hello | java Subprocess    
   // Windows should uppercase the file and exit:
   type somefile.txt | java Subprocess
   // Linux should uppercase the file and exit:
   cat somefile.txt | java Subprocess
   ```
3. The `subprocess.waitFor()` must be at the end after dealing with the sub-process `subprocess.getInputStream()` and `subprocess.getOutputStream()`. Those streams won't be valid after this call ends:

   ```
    int rc = subprocess.waitFor();
   ```
4. You have one loop that tries to deal with reading both scanner and stdout of sub-process at same time - this won't work reliably. The main loop should not care how many lines the sub-process writes for each line sent to it. You can avoid linking the two problems by using a background thread to copy all the STDOUT of the subprocess and leaving the main loop to handle your scanner input only. Make sure the background thread has ended before calling `subprocess.waitFor()`.
5. The loop over scanner is incorrect, it does not deal with `scanner.readLine()` is null.